# How to get height of div and set width as height in Windows 8

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a div. I've set the width of the div to auto. I want this div to be a square, so I've set the height of the div to 100%. Now if I set the width of the div to 100% it wouldn't be a square as most screens are rectangle, so I thought I could get the current height of the div in pixels and set the width as the height in landscape mode, and do the opposite in portrait mode, but I have no idea about how to go about this. Please assist me for the same. I'm using HTML and JavaScript

[image]

Comment: Are you unsure about, how to set the width of the div or how to check the current mode, or both?

Answer (score 3):

Without any extension like jQuery:

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var height = div.clientHeight;
div.style.width = height + 'px';
```

Comment: Note: `offsetHeight` will return value of the height including the border which might make your `div` not an actual square.

Comment: [Consider using `clientHeight` instead of `offsetHeight`](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/PsTAt/) since `clientHeight` will return the true height.

Comment: Yes you're right! `offsetHeight` would only work if the border is zero. I've changed it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think JavaScript is necessary for that; if you are doing mobile/tablet design you could use media queries to change the width and height of your div; and if you want it to be square you could set the width and height to be the same with CSS. Experiment with percentages until you find which values produce equal width and height in web developer or firebug.